# How to make Text widget visible if ListView snapshot returns empty?

Tags: android, flutter

Here am trying to show a text widget if the snapshot of cart items has no values in it, what I tried is snapshot.hasData inside default case but didn't succeed and is there ay better way to do it? am building an e-commerce app wherein I have a cart page containing this code below to load all cart items.

```
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: db
          .collection('login')
          .document(_userId)
          .collection('cartItems')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Text('Loading...');
          default:
              return ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                children:
                    snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 110,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Container(
                            width: 100.0,
                            child: ListTile(
                                trailing: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                                  onPressed: () async {
                                    db
                                        .collection('login')
                                        .document(_userId)
                                        .collection('cartItems')
                                        .document(document['model'])
                                        .delete();
                                  },
                                ),
                                leading: Image.network(
                                  document['image'],
                                  width: 100.0,
                                  height: 100.0,
                                ),
                                subtitle: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      document['model'],
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      "₹" + document['price'],
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 18.0,
                                          color: Colors.black45),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            }
      },
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me but is this the conventional way ?

```
if(snapshot.data.documents.isEmpty){
                return Center(
                  child: Text('Your Cart is empty!',style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 30,
                    color: Colors.black
                  ),),
                );
```